# MAC address spoofing not working in Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac-address

In Windows 7 I tried setting my MAC address by changing it via adapter properties (Locally Administered MAC Address), but ipconfig /all still shows the old address, even after rebooting. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible your card does not support changing your mac address.

You may also have more luck with a [mac address changing utility](http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/).

Edit: It seems things are slightly different on Windows 7

(Taken from a forum post);

1. Go to Control Panel->Device Manage->Network Adapter->Advanced->Network Address
2. Change the value here. **Ensure the first two digits are not the same**.
3. Change the registry key value. ([Guide here](http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/how-to-change-mac-address-in-windows-registry/)).

Comment: Are you sure that this is something that the network card would need to support? Unless you have a network accelerator card, aren't Ethernet headers are generated in-kernel?

Comment: Interesting thought. I think after the driver calls NdisReadNetworkAddress() it can decide whether or not to accept the user-provided address before saving it in hardware registers. The burned-in one can definitely never be changed, but I was under the impression it was optional for a device to accept user-defined mac addresses.

Comment: I found a couple references, through a quick google, that show that this will not work in every situation...

Comment: I know my laptop can forge the MAC address - I was able to do this in XP, but not in 7. Been a while since I tried this, so I'm marking this accepted, though I never found a resolution to my problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

http://devices.natetrue.com/macshift/ will succeed where others have failed. Though sometimes the MAC address is burned into the EEEPROM of the card.

Comment: The page says it only works for XP....

Comment: Well, if you have XP it works great.  I couldn't change it with SMAC or any other utility but this worked.

Comment: @LawrenceC Yang Kelbizzle the download link is dead, please, would you like to reupload it here?

Answer (score -3):

Try a MAC address starting with 10, 12, 13, 14 or something like that.

Not all MAC addresses are supported in Windows 7.

Comment: "Not all MAC addresses are supported in Windows 7." - Please backup this statement otherwise I will assume its just a bunch of FUD.