# Spoofing MAC address to match other device

Tags: windows-7, mac-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when two PCs have the same MAC adress?](https://superuser.com/questions/17696/what-happens-when-two-pcs-have-the-same-mac-adress)

At my school, there is a WiFi network where you can register up to one computer or phone. I, however, wish to connect my phone and my computer (Windows 7). I talked to an IT guy at my school and he told me that it registers the computer based on the MAC address (For the record, he's the one who suggested I spoof). So, I got my phone's MAC and now I want to change my computer's address to the same thing. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/90222/mac-address-spoofing-not-working-in-windows) link and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=sfAWXuCfCqI#at=17) video, so I know how to change it. 

I was wondering if that would run into problems because they are normally on the same network at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same MAC address for both the computer and the phone **at the same time** at home then you will have problems.

If you wait about 10 minutes then the ARP cache from your OS will time-out and no problem will occur.

If you want to more details read up on TCP/IP and ARP.

Comment: So I wait connect one then wait ~ 10 minutes then connect another it'll be fine? Is that what you're saying? Just to clarify...

Comment: No. You can't have two devices with the same MAC connected simultaneously. So, you disconnect first device, then connect another.